# How to get Visual Studio Code to configure and find .NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, asp.net5

I tried setting up Visual Studio Code for .NET 5 after downloading it from the website. Currently the error I'm getting is:

> g:\DatingApp\API\API.csproj(0,0): Error: Unable to resolve 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (>= 5.6.3)' for 'net5.0'.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: where did you get this project?

Comment: Did you check that the Swashbuckel.AspNetCore package supports .Net 5? You may need to update or change to use a different package.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to your project properties for your existing project/solution, you can change it in the application tab:

[image]

Comment: The OP is about Visual Studio Code, and not regular Visual Studio.